# Color change on buttons whenever focused

Tags: css

:( Not working for me. Below style is working if I give the button id. BUT I don't want to use the id instead should apply on all buttons whenever button is focused.
I tried with .btn class not no success.

**This is working**

```
button#mybutton:focus
{
     background:olive;
}
```

**Updated**

Sorry if I am not clear. I am using METRONIC theme and was not feasible to post whole HTML Page. I thought anyone could simply use HTML page to test it. Like and answer below.

I tested the focus on a simple HTML page and its working but METRONIC theme somehow not letting me change button focus color till I use Button id.
Any solution?

Comment: yes it won't work without HTML

Comment: Please post enough for is to be able to see what is wrong. CSS and HTML

Comment: @intervalia posted an update

Comment: @temani-afif posted an update.

Comment: If you know how to use developer tools then look at the button and turn on hover and see what the CSS is currently so you can determine how to be more specific then the existing CSS rules. If you can then post the rule that is setting the background color then we can provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have not provide complete info about your code but you said you want to apply a style on every single button whenever is it focused(tageted by keyboard).
Here is the css code you want with html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  button:focus {
    background-color: olive;
  }
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="mybutton">i am a button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to find errors in your code or something please provide more information about it

Comment: Try using !important at the end of css statement(make sure the other stylesheet file does not have this property for buttons) and see if it helps.  example :background-color: olive !important;

Comment: Using `!important` should be a **last** resort. I only use it for debugging and for having a print stylesheet force the output to hide/show/color what I want to print. Beyond that I suggest learning CSS Specificity rules instead of `!important`. Once you use that you are creating a CSS override nightmare. https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: You are definitely right about this but I wanted to know what is causing the problem here since he has to specify more about an element to be selected.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at this mdn article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity cause you should avoid using !important.also could you give a up vote if the solution worked ? Good Luck @Ali